# ListBoxFor losing selected values on submitting the page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am facing problem in selecting the items in ListBoxFor control on submit. I am using a PagedListPager control and when selecting the next page the ListBoxFor control is losing the selected values and throwing error.

Here is my code:

ViewModel:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FiscalYearsData { get; set };
public IEnumerable<int> SelectedYears { get; set; }
```

Controller (Loading FiscalYearsData from repository as below):

```
fourteenStepStatusView.FiscalYearsData = 
projectRepository.GetFiscalYears.Select
(yr => new SelectListItem { Text = yr.ToString(), Value = yr.ToString()}).ToList();
```

View:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedYears, new      
MultiSelectList(Model.FiscalYearsData, "Value", "Text", Model.SelectedYears),  
new { @Id = "lstFiscalYears", @class = "ListBoxFor70Style", Multiple = "multiple", 
size = "3" })
```

Can anyone help me in solving the same. I am not sure what mistake I am doing here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Umm... Yeah. The page links are just standard old links that cause your browser to issue a GET request for the next page. It's not posting your form each time. The only way to preserve any list box selections between pages would be to either use AJAX to update a backend version of the list or use JavaScript to mangle the query string on the page links to include the selections every time they change.

As usual, the better approach is probably to just stop and rethink what you're trying to achieve. Dollars to dimes there's a better way.

Comment: Thank you Chris for the quick response. When I am debugging the code, able to see the call going to Controller's method on every page selection from PagedListPager control.

Comment: Try to set a breakpoint in your SelectListItem statement and see if it's being called.

Comment: If you are talking about Controller Call. Yes, it is stopping on the breakpoint on every page number selection

Answer (score 0):

Try any one of the below: (both would work)

Change SelectedYears property as follows

```
public IEnumerable<string> SelectedYears { get; set; }
```

OR

Changes the service call for getting fiscal years as follows

```
fourteenStepStatusView.FiscalYearsData = projectRepository.GetFiscalYears.Select
(yr => new SelectListItem { Text = yr.ToString(), Value = (int)yr}).ToList()
```

Comment: Thank you Vvutpala for your response. The second option will not work as the "Value" takes string type. I tried already with the first option but it is returning "string" as it's value on submission to the form.